# model returned to view has no effect on field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor

My Model;

```
namespace GeneralUtility.Models
{
  public class MyModel
  {
    public int BirthDateYear { get; set; } 
    public String Details { get; set; }
  }
}
```

My Controller

```
namespace GeneralUtility.Controllers
{
  public class WorkspaceController : Controller
  {
     public ActionResult MyHelper(MyModel model)
    {
      if(model.someCondition)
         model.Details= "TEST";
      else
         model.Details= "Some other TEST";   

     return View(model);
    }
  }
}
```

My View

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("MyHelper", "WorkSpace", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmMyForm" }))
  {
     ...
     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Details )
     </div>
     ...
  }
</div>
```

After I submit my form, I can see the model and any changes I make in MyHelper action method. However, when I make changes and return the model from the controller (I can see the changes in the model while in debug). I get the same value as before in `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Details )` field. What can I do to get the changed Details value of the model to show?

Comment: Have you tried using `ModelState.Clear()` before the if statement

Comment: I assume you are using a strongly typed view of GeneralUtility.Models.MyModel?

Comment: I tried it just now and it works. Thanks. I'll accept it if you post as answer. I would appreciate it if you would tell me why it works. I thought it cleared model contents but it doesnt seem to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because by default ASP.NET MVC returns the model that was passed into a method (using what is stored in the `ModelState`, if it exists). If it doesn't exist, it uses what you pass to the View.

In order to prevent this, you need to call `ModelState.Clear()` before returning your view.

Check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx) for a more detailed explanation.